# GCC accessing thread local storage unnecessarily?

Tags: gcc, assembly, simd

I'm running down some numeric difference between GCC/ICC and I've noticed something puzzling.  When compiling this function (which computes an approximate natural logarithm):

```
// convenience macros for defining constant vectors
#define MM256_ICONST(val) (__m256)_mm256_set1_epi32(val);
#define MM256_FCONST(val)         _mm256_set1_ps   (val);

__m256 _mm256_logf_app(__m256 xx) {
    // constants
    const __m256 mant_mask = MM256_ICONST(0x007FFFFF); // mantissa mask
    const __m256  exp_mask = MM256_ICONST(0x3F800000); // 127 in exponent
    const __m256      mln2 = MM256_FCONST(M_LN2);      // log(2)

    // polynomial coefficients
    const __m256 a = MM256_FCONST(+3.529304993f);
    const __m256 b = MM256_FCONST(-2.461222105f);
    const __m256 c = MM256_FCONST(+1.130626167f);
    const __m256 d = MM256_FCONST(-0.288739945f);
    const __m256 e = MM256_FCONST(+3.110401639e-2f);
    const __m256 f = MM256_FCONST(-89.970756366f);

    // mask out anything <= 0
    __m256 invalid = _mm256_cmp_ps(xx, _mm256_setzero_ps(), _CMP_LE_OQ);

    // extract exponents
    __m256 exp = _mm256_cvtepi32_ps(
        avx2_mm256_srli_epi32((__m256i)xx, 23)
    );

    // clear exponent to 0 (+127)
    xx = _mm256_and_ps(xx, mant_mask);
    xx = _mm256_or_ps (xx,  exp_mask);

    // horner's rule to evaluate polynomial
    __m256 ret = e;
    ret = _mm256_add_ps(d, _mm256_mul_ps(ret,xx));
    ret = _mm256_add_ps(c, _mm256_mul_ps(ret,xx));
    ret = _mm256_add_ps(b, _mm256_mul_ps(ret,xx));
    ret = _mm256_add_ps(a, _mm256_mul_ps(ret,xx));
    ret = _mm256_add_ps(f, _mm256_mul_ps(ret,xx));

    // add in exponent contribution
    ret = _mm256_add_ps(ret,
        _mm256_mul_ps(exp, mln2)
    );

    return _mm256_or_ps(ret, invalid);
}
```

It generates this assembly:

```
   0x00000000006f0f10 <+0>:     lea    0x8(%rsp),%r10
   0x00000000006f0f15 <+5>:     and    $0xffffffffffffffe0,%rsp
   0x00000000006f0f19 <+9>:     pushq  -0x8(%r10)
   0x00000000006f0f1d <+13>:    push   %rbp
   0x00000000006f0f1e <+14>:    mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x00000000006f0f21 <+17>:    push   %r10
   0x00000000006f0f23 <+19>:    sub    $0x68,%rsp
   0x00000000006f0f27 <+23>:    vmovaps %ymm0,-0x70(%rbp)
   0x00000000006f0f2c <+28>:    vxorps %xmm0,%xmm0,%xmm0
   0x00000000006f0f30 <+32>:    vmovaps -0x70(%rbp),%ymm4
   0x00000000006f0f35 <+37>:    vmovdqa -0x70(%rbp),%xmm1
   0x00000000006f0f3a <+42>:    vandps 0x3dade(%rip),%ymm4,%ymm8
   0x00000000006f0f42 <+50>:    vcmple_oqps %ymm0,%ymm4,%ymm3
   0x00000000006f0f47 <+55>:    vmovdqa -0x60(%rbp),%xmm5
   0x00000000006f0f4c <+60>:    vpsrld $0x17,%xmm1,%xmm2
   0x00000000006f0f51 <+65>:    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
   0x00000000006f0f5a <+74>:    mov    %rax,-0x18(%rbp)
   0x00000000006f0f5e <+78>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x00000000006f0f60 <+80>:    vpsrld $0x17,%xmm5,%xmm6
   0x00000000006f0f65 <+85>:    vmovaps %xmm2,-0x50(%rbp)
   0x00000000006f0f6a <+90>:    mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
   0x00000000006f0f6e <+94>:    xor    %fs:0x28,%rax
   0x00000000006f0f77 <+103>:   vmovaps %xmm6,-0x40(%rbp)
   0x00000000006f0f7c <+108>:   vcvtdq2ps -0x50(%rbp),%ymm7
   0x00000000006f0f81 <+113>:   vorps  0x3dab7(%rip),%ymm8,%ymm9
   0x00000000006f0f89 <+121>:   vmulps 0x3db6f(%rip),%ymm7,%ymm1
   0x00000000006f0f91 <+129>:   vmulps 0x3dac7(%rip),%ymm9,%ymm10 
   0x00000000006f0f99 <+137>:   vaddps 0x3db7f(%rip),%ymm1,%ymm5 
   0x00000000006f0fa1 <+145>:   vaddps 0x3dad7(%rip),%ymm10,%ymm11
   0x00000000006f0fa9 <+153>:   vmulps %ymm9,%ymm11,%ymm12
   0x00000000006f0fae <+158>:   vaddps 0x3daea(%rip),%ymm12,%ymm13
   0x00000000006f0fb6 <+166>:   vmulps %ymm9,%ymm13,%ymm14
   0x00000000006f0fbb <+171>:   vaddps 0x3dafd(%rip),%ymm14,%ymm15
   0x00000000006f0fc3 <+179>:   vmulps %ymm9,%ymm15,%ymm0
   0x00000000006f0fc8 <+184>:   vaddps 0x3db10(%rip),%ymm0,%ymm4
   0x00000000006f0fd0 <+192>:   vmulps %ymm9,%ymm4,%ymm2
   0x00000000006f0fd5 <+197>:   vaddps %ymm5,%ymm2,%ymm6
   0x00000000006f0fd9 <+201>:   vorps  %ymm3,%ymm6,%ymm0
   0x00000000006f0fdd <+205>:   jne    0x6f0fea <_mm256_logf_app(float __vector(8))+218>
   0x00000000006f0fdf <+207>:   add    $0x68,%rsp
   0x00000000006f0fe3 <+211>:   pop    %rax
   0x00000000006f0fe4 <+212>:   pop    %rbp
   0x00000000006f0fe5 <+213>:   lea    -0x8(%rax),%rsp
   0x00000000006f0fe9 <+217>:   retq
```

The puzzling thing is this piece:

```
   0x00000000006f0f51 <+65>:    mov    %fs:0x28,%rax
   0x00000000006f0f5a <+74>:    mov    %rax,-0x18(%rbp)
   0x00000000006f0f5e <+78>:    xor    %eax,%eax
   0x00000000006f0f60 <+80>:    vpsrld $0x17,%xmm5,%xmm6
   0x00000000006f0f65 <+85>:    vmovaps %xmm2,-0x50(%rbp)
   0x00000000006f0f6a <+90>:    mov    -0x18(%rbp),%rax
   0x00000000006f0f6e <+94>:    xor    %fs:0x28,%rax
```

Which looks to me like an access of thread-local storage (fs register, I'm on x64 linux).  It pulls from TLS, spills to the stack, then xors with something from TLS again?  Why is it doing this? Intel doesn't.  This is GCC 7.3

compiled with:

```
> g++ -std=c++11 -O3 -g3 -Wall -Wextra -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fopenmp -pthread -Idep/opt/include -Iinc/  -ffast-math -fPIC -mavx -funroll-loops -c lib/simd_avx.cc -o lib/simd_avx.o
```

Comment: That's the [stack protector](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html#index-fstack-protector). Add `-fno-stack-protector`. It's not obvious to me why gcc decided to add it here as I can't spot anything that normally triggers it.

Comment: Ah excellent, thank you.  The intel version I'm fighting with is older so it doesn't have stack protection

Comment: The only thing inside the protected region is the `vmovaps %xmm2,-0x50(%rbp)` which is a store of a known size to an automatic variable allocated by the compiler ... should be safe. There is nothing in the function to warrant a protector unless you have `-fstack-protector-all` or `-fstack-protector-strong` enabled by default for some reason.

Comment: Yeah I don't have it on at all as far as I know...

Comment: It looks like you compiled with optimization disabled;  spilling `xx` to the stack on function entry is horrible.  If you're looking at the asm for code with intrinsics, definitely use `-O1` at least, preferably `-O3`.  That might even optimize away the stack-protector stuff, because it can spend enough time optimizing to prove that this function doesn't need the stack protector code.  And BTW, stack-protector isn't just a newer/older gcc thing.  Your distro chose to configure the default setting to `-fstack-protector-strong`, but off is another possible setting for modern GCC.

Comment: e.g. actual gcc7.3 -O3 output is https://godbolt.org/z/dGjO20 with no stack access.  (Godbolt builds gcc with stack-protector disabled, but manually enabling it still adds no overhead to this function when `-O3 -march=haswell` is used to enable AVX2 and FMA.  You didn't show a definition for `avx2_mm256_srli_epi32`, so maybe your definition is inlining some code that uses crappy pointer-casting instead of `_mm256_extractf128_ps` if you compile without AVX2, resulting in store/reload?  Still looks like un-optimized code, though.)

Comment: This is GCC that comes with Ubuntu 18, I'm not sure if it has the stack protector enabled by default or not.  avx2_mm256_srli_epi32 splits into xmm registers using a union, I should probably change that.